# Consumers re-render when Provider re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats)

> the code below will re-render all consumers every time the Provider re-renders because a new object is always created for value

So i made a simple example to test this:

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: {something: 'something'},
    };
  }
  render() {
   console.log('App');
    return (
    <>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state.value}>
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
       {(value)=>( <Toolbar test={value}/>)}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      <button onClick={this.handler}>click me</button>
      </>
    );
  }

  handler=()=>{
  this.forceUpdate()
  }
}

const app =  <App />;

class Toolbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
   console.log('Toolbar');
    return (
     <div></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(app,mountNode);
```

It seems that in every click, even though the reference is the same, toolbar component re-renders along with provider. So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the consumer as direct children of App will cause them to render when App component re-renders instead you must write your code as

```js
const ThemeContext = React.createContext();
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: {something: 'something'},
    };
  }
  render() {
   console.log('App');
    return (
     <React.Fragment>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state.value}>
          {this.props.children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      <button onClick={this.handler}>click me</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  handler=()=>{
    this.forceUpdate()
  }
}

const app =  (<App>
               <ThemeContext.Consumer>
                  {(value)=>( <Toolbar test={value}/>)}
                </ThemeContext.Consumer>
             </App>)

class Toolbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
   console.log('Toolbar');
    return (
     <div></div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: It works, but here Consumer is again a direct child of Provider right?

Comment: Not in the tree directly

Comment: --APP  --PROVIDER  --CONSUMER  --TOOLBAR  DIV TOOLBAR--  CONSUMER--  PROVIDER--  APP--.  This is the tree that is generated from react in both cases (my example and yours), its exactly the same. What is the difference that doesnt trigger the rendering on the consumer?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: {something: 'something'},
    };
  }

   handler(){
    this.forceUpdate()
    }

  render() {
   console.log('App');
    return (
    <div>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state.value}>
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
       {(value)=>( <Toolbar test={value}/>)}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      <button onClick={this.handler}>click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }


}

const app =  <App />;

class Toolbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
   console.log('Toolbar');
    return (
     <div></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(app,mountNode);
```

Comment: add div Element instead of <> and also change your inline function is my change .